# For Loop Map Overwrites Previous Value

Tags: java, sockets, dictionary

Essentially I am making a board game using sockets. Each client connected is stored in a map .

When the user makes a move to a coordinate in the 2D Array i.e. "move 2,3", it should put the connectionID in that position.

Currently my issue is, because I have a for loop; when i use the move command, the connection ID is replaced with the last value in the loop.

```
public void move(int x, int y) {
    for (int value : gs.returnClients().values()) {
        storeArray[x][y] = value;
    }
}
```

i.e. If i have 2 clients connected: `{62029=1, 62032=2}` and my board

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Let's say I want to have client 1 move to 0, 3 it should be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But instead I get:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Since it's overwriting the last value of the map in the for loop.

How would I make it move dependent on its client "id" from the map?

Edit

In my server i have `clients.put(socket.getPort(), connectionID);` and methods to return the map and id. I have a class `GameService` that executes command which is

```
switch (request.type) {
       case MOVE:
            int clientID = Integer.parseInt(request.params[0]);
            int getX = Integer.parseInt(request.params[1]);
            int getY = Integer.parseInt(request.params[2]);
            game.move(clientID,getX, getY);
            return game.returnBoard();
```

In a file `Request`

```
String[] items = line.trim().split("\\s+");
            switch (items[0].toUpperCase()) {
                case "MOVE":
                    return new Request(RequestType.MOVE, items[1], items[2], items[3]);
```

Comment: if I interpret your code correctly, then you shouldn't need to iterate over all `returnClients().values()` but instead use **the** client for whom the moves need to be registered....

Comment: @Roland could you possibly give a general example? Not quite sure what you mean in terms of coding this

Comment: Why are you using loop here? What is its purpose?

Comment: @Pshemo well i wanted to loop through the clients(map) and plot the value in the 2d array that links with the unique ID. But this approach didn't work because it overwrites the previous value with the next one

Comment: Assigning one value to specific cell in array doesn't require loop so I still don't see why would you want to use it here. If you know what value should be placed in array you just need `storeArray[x][y] = valueYouWant;`. Here `valueYouWant` is ID of user who makes a move. Since that is most obvious way to write it and you didn't write it that way I suspect it is because you can't do it, because are facing *some other problem* which you didn't told us about yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your code, you need to do your move the following way:

```
public void move(int client, int x, int y) {
  storeArray[x][y] = client;
}
```

where client is one (!) of the numbers within the `gs.returnClients().values()`-list. If you need to take it out of that map, you need to deliver the appropriate key for that, e.g.:

```
public void move(int clientId, int x, int y) {
  storeArray[x][y] = gs.returnClients().get(clientId);
}
```

Comment: I see but with this approach my move command then has to change to the user specifying their own ID? I.e. `move 1 2 3` meaning any client can move any other client?

Comment: I don't see the rest of your code... of course the client should not send its id, but rather the "server" should handle that... how do you identify the client? what is the key of that method?

Comment: if the client connects to the server, you have its ~id... with that id you take the move... so: whenever that client sends the server a message (like move to x/y), then the server "knows" its id and just calls `move(thatId, x, y)`....

Comment: the part i am confused on is, if we are adding a 3rd argument. How would you use this when typing move x x x. You will always have to enter that 3rd argument?

Comment: @godlypython I don't see why you need third argument representing client (I am assuming you are talking about client side). Server should know from which stream it read data and which client that stream belongs to.

Comment: Ok so..i've made a bit of progres..ive gotten the client unique ID but currently its stored in an array. How would i use the map.get from an arrayList

Comment: other question: how do you get the command from the client? somewhere there you have the ~connectionId or ~sessionId or ~portId.... take that id and extract the appropriate value from the map with it... that's it ;-)